# Writing data to an sql database upon payment completed

Tags: php, sql, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce

I am attempting to take information from a woocommerce order, put it into variables, and write it to an SQL database. I can properly retrieve and process the data. I have even managed to write it to the database if I run it manually.

I cannot seem to get the action hook to work yet with the script.

I followed what I have seen for people doing similar things on here but so far it has not worked. I have 3 main questions:

1. Can I define the order id inside of the function,
2. Do I need to call the function somewhere else,
3. Is this action hook properly set up to run after the payment is processed.

Function is below:

```
add_action('woocommerce_payment_complete', 'returnAttributesFromCheckout');
function returnAttributesFromCheckout ($order_id) {

    $connection = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'apptest');

    if(!$connection) {

        die('ded' . mysqli_error($connection));
    }

    global $woocommerce, $post;

    $order = new WC_Order($order_id);

    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data) {

        // Get an instance of corresponding the WC_Product object
        $product = $item_data->get_product();

        $rank = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_rank' );
        $money = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_money' );
        $spawner = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_spawner' );
        $permission = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_permission' );
        $kit = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_kit' );
        $crate = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_crate' );
        $tag = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_stag' );
        $duration = $product->get_attribute( 'pa_duration' );
        $d = strtotime("+ $duration Months");
        $endDate = date("d/m/Y", $d);

        $query = "INSERT INTO checkout(rank, money) ";
        $query .= "VALUES('$rank', '$money')";

        $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);

        if(!$result) {

            die('its dead jim' . mysqli_error($connection));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: See about parametrised queries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This hook is only applied on paid orders *(outside "COD", "BACS" and "cheque" payment methods)* and order status is always set to "processing or "completed". But if you are testing this on a Test payment gateway account and if the received transaction feedback parameters are missing, the order will looks like paid but it will remains in an "on-hold" status, so the hook will not be fired.

I have tested the hook with Paypal and another credit card payment gateways, and it's fired correctly when a transaction is paid and order status is set to "processing or "completed".

Now To avoid that problems, you could target "processing" / "completed" orders status using instead `woocommerce_order_status_changed`.

Also instead of using classic PHP SQL connection, you should use dedicated [wpdb class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) in Wordpress/Woocommerce code.

Below I have revisited your code using that [wpdb class](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb). Here is the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'checkout_custom_table_insert', 20, 4 );
function checkout_custom_table_insert( $order_id, $old_status, $new_status, $order ){

    // Only for 'processing' and 'completed' order status changes
    $statuses = array( 'processing', 'completed' );
    if ( ! in_array( $new_status, $statuses ) ) return;

    // Check if data has been already updated (avoid repetitions)
    $is_done = get_post_meta( $order_id, '_checkout_table_updated', true );
    if( ! empty($is_done) ) return; // We exit if it has been already done

    global $wpdb;

    // Loop through order items
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item){
        $product = $item->get_product(); // Get the variation product object

        // Choose in the array which data you want to insert (each line is a table column)
        $args = array(
            'rank'          => $product->get_attribute( 'pa_rank' ),
            'money'         => $product->get_attribute( 'pa_money' ),
            'spawner'       => $product->get_attribute( 'pa_spawner' ),
            'permission'    => $product->get_attribute( 'pa_permission' ),
            'kit'           => $product->get_attribute( 'pa_kit' ),
            'crate'         => $product->get_attribute( 'pa_crate' ),
            'stag'          => $product->get_attribute( 'pa_stag' ),
            'duration'      => $product->get_attribute( 'pa_duration' ),
            'end_date'      => date("d/m/Y", strtotime("+ $duration Months")),
        );

        // The SQL INSERT query
        $table = "checkout" // or "{$wpdb->prefix}checkout";
        $wpdb->insert(  $table, $args ); // Insert the data
    }

    // Mark this task as done for this order
    update_post_meta( $order_id, '_checkout_table_updated', '1' );
}
```

*Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme).*

This should better work…

---

Comment: How exactly do I check that it is correctly prefixed? I'm not entirely sure what you are referring to. The database my original program links to is actually separate from the database wordpress sets up upon creation of the website, I'm not sure if that makes a difference or not

Comment: one more thing, does the function pull all the info that it is supposed to be passed on its own or do I need to pass it those values?

Comment: So I am having an issue with receiving the order, I'm using PayPal sandbox and when woocommere receives the order it sets it as pending and never moves it to processing or to completed status. Will the event still fire if I do it manually?

Comment: @Bman76 I have maid some slight changes in the code. Yes you can manually change the order status from "pending" to "processing" *(or "completed")* and the hook will be fired too, so your data will be pulled from the current product variation and will be pushed to your custom table "checkout"…

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. I just did a final check and everything works.